# 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am new on flutter
I want to make Responsive UI but I got this problem[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      // First Column - HomeView
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: HomeView(),
      ),

      // Second Column - ChatRoomView
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: ChatRoomView(),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

this may code I try it but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: post here what is inside of `ChatRoomView` as the error is in there

Comment: how put code in this comment?

Comment: Hi bro, My advice was not about comment but inside of question (you enter in edit then add the missed part)